# Add array list to a list inside for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to add array list to a list inside for loop. in my code, ***scenario*** 
is array list and it is suppose to be has a new values in every ***i*** . for every ***i*** i want to save the ***scenario*** inside a list ***list_of_scenarios*** but i have this error.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
```

Any idea about how can i fix it?

```
    int[] ActionArrayTest = new int[25];
    int[] test27Augest = new int[75];
    ArrayList<Hour> scenario = new ArrayList<Hour>();
    List<ArrayList<Hour>> list_of_scenarios = new  ArrayList<ArrayList<Hour>>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

        ActionArrayTest = FunctionA (); 

        test27Augest = Fill_the_prefrences(ActionArrayTest);
        scenario = FunctionB(test27Augest);


    list_of_scenarios.add(i, scenario);


    }
```

Comment: read the doc for the method that throw the exception, at least.

Comment: you are starting your loop at position 1 .. and your array list is empty at that time .. start at position 0

Comment: Just use `list_of_scenarios.add(scenario);` or start `i` with 0 rather than 1.

Answer (score 0):

On the first iteration of your loop, `list_of_scenarios.add(i, scenario);` is asking to add `scenario` to index 1 in your ArrayList. However, at that point, your `ArrayList` is empty.

Proposed fix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    ActionArrayTest = FunctionA (); 

    test27Augest = Fill_the_prefrences(ActionArrayTest);
    scenario = FunctionB(test27Augest);


    list_of_scenarios.add(i, scenario);

}
```

Note: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)) states that this method adds the element at that index, but shifts everything else to the right.

If you want to structure your `ArrayList` such that the element at index 0 was added before the element at index 1, use the plain `add()` method:

`list_of_scenarios.add(scenario);`

[This method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) simply adds the element to the 'end' of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create an arraylist of arraylists..Doesnt sound like a good programming approach. If you want to find an element inside that list of lists, it is going to take lot of time. Think about the code complexity to find the last element in the last arraylist. You have to iterate through the list of lists, get each list, iterate through the each list again to find that element.

If all those arraylists have same type, why cant you just add all those elements to the top array list. So you maintain only one arraylist and as you go through the for loop, you add the elements of Scenario to the arraylist.

like this..

```
List<Hour> list_of_scenarios = new  ArrayList<Hour>();
 for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    ActionArrayTest = FunctionA (); 
    test27Augest = Fill_the_prefrences(ActionArrayTest);
    scenario = FunctionB(test27Augest);
    //add all the elements of 'scenario' to the list.
    list_of_scenarios.addAll(scenario); 
}
```

Good luck..Happy programming.. :)

Comment: You should preclude your code-improvement-suggestion with an explanation for why OP is getting the error they are getting, as that would be the actual answer to this question.

Comment: i can only give what i know. It is surprising to see people bringing jealous or some sort of annoying things here. It is supposed to knowledge sharing platform. i did not say my answer is right. I only gave what i know and it is up to the user to decide whether to use it or not.  Looking forward to work with smart and good developers.